# In the 1969 episode, why is all the equipment covered

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the [1969](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/1969_(episode)) episode, SG1 goes too far forward in time, where an old Cassandra turns them back. Every piece of equipment, in future StarGate room is covered by sheets.

Up until now I always assumed those were "not in use" covers, similarly [to how furniture is covered when not in use](https://londonsashwindows.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/dust-sheets-covering-london-house.jpg).

Is this the case, or was the equipment covered to not expose it to past SG1 eyes ?

Comment: The implication, given Cassandra is the only one to meet them, is that the SGC is shut down or decommissioned, and perhaps no longer needed.  If it was just to prevent time hijinks or too much awareness, they'd have had a more formal reception.  (The other implication is that the writers probably had no idea what the SGC should look like some decades forward).

Answer (score 11):

It was just an indication that the Stargate Command was not longer in active use.  Nobody seemed to be there except Cassandra, who was only present because she had (presumably) been previously informed that she would need to meet the SG-1 on that date.

It was also a callback to the very first shot of the *SG-1* television series, which featured the gate room and control room draped in cover cloths, indicating that the facility was in the process of being mothballed.